# SELECT Average Count of IIS method calls per second

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find out the average count of IIS calls per second (GET, POST, PUT, etc) in a time span of one week

Here's an example of a SELECT I'd use to get total counts in a week:

```
  SELECT Method, COUNT(*) 
      AS TotalCalls
    FROM IISLog
   WHERE dDate 
 BETWEEN '2018-05-10' 
     AND '2018-05-17'
GROUP BY Method
```

How can I granularise this SELECT to get an average count of Method calls per second in this date range?

Expected output for calls per second:

```
Method    CallsPerSecond
Get       15
Put       10
Post      14
Delete    12
```

The number counts are just example estimates

Comment: So, what is your question here exactly? You've stated your goal, good, and you've provided your expected results, also good. You've given us your SQL, good too. You haven't, however, asked a question.

Comment: On a different note, the clause `WHERE dDate BETWEEN '2018-05-10' AND '2018-05-10'` is the same as `WHERE dDate = '2018-05-10'` (and that will only return rows with a time of exactly `00:00:00.0000000`). What is the goal of your `BETWEEN` statement here? If it's to return rows that occur at any time on that day it would be `WHERE dDate >= '20181005' AND dDate < '20181006'`. (assume your format is `yyyy-dd-MM`)

Comment: @Larnu Sorry Larnu, edited to add question and change end date to '2018-05-17'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just divide by the amount of seconds that compose your filter ranges.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2018-05-10'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2018-05-17'

SELECT 
    Method, 
    CallsPerSecond = COUNT(*) / NULLIF(DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartDate, @EndDate), 0),
    TotalCalls = COUNT(*)
FROM 
    IISLog AS I
WHERE 
    I.dDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY 
    I.Method
```

Comment: You beat me to it. :P

Comment: I would, however, suggest changing `I.dDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate` to `I.dDate >= @StartDate AND I.dDate < @EndDate`, as `BETWEEN` would include the datetime `2018-05-17T00:00:00.000` (but no other times from that day).